# Importing CSV file into PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, csv, import

Using MySQL Administrator GUI tool I have exported some data tables retrieved from an sql dumpfile to csv files.

I then tried to import these CSV files into a PostgreSQL database using the postgres COPY command. I've tried entering

```
COPY articles FROM '[insert .csv dir here]' DELIMITERS ',' CSV;
```

and also the same command without the delimiters part.

I get an error saying

```
ERROR: invalid input syntax for integer: "id"
CONTEXT: COPY articles, line 1, column id: "id"
```

In conclusion my question is what are some thoughts and solutions to this problem? Could it possibly be something to do with the way I created the csv files? or have I made a rookie mistake elsewhere?

Comment: Has you CSV file got a 'title' line across the top?

Comment: I'm just wondering why you tagged your question as python? (am I missing something really obvious?)

Comment: Write some scripts to populate the table, by reading your CSV file.

Comment: Well I was open to some python suggestions since I did remove the non-ascii chars from the csv files using python, but yeah Gavin seemed to have solved my problem. Thanks for the input though.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you have header columns just add the header qualifier to the copy statement as per
documentation to skip that line
http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.4/static/sql-copy.html

Comment: COPY articles FROM '[insert .csv dir here]' CSV WITH HEADER;

Comment: Ah yeah awesome. Thanks so much this worked well. lol although it did produce a lot of unwanted white space in the data put into the table, but I guess thats a new problem I have to try and solve.

Comment: Oh disregard what I said about the post-problem encountered. I didnt realise that the data is actually squished and displays wierdly when viewing it in the terminal.